# How to stream a local video to webcam using ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, video-editing

I have a local video and I want to stream it to a dummy webcam video device from `v4l2loopback`. I created the dummy device at `/dev/video1`. How to use `ffmpeg` to steam that local video `trial_video.mp4` to the dummy device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this AU Q&A titled: [Is there any way ffmpeg send video to /dev/video0 on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881305/is-there-any-way-ffmpeg-send-video-to-dev-video0-on-ubuntu) you can do the following:

```
$ ffmpeg -re -i trial_video.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```